# Mining and Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: wallet, mining-profitability, hashpower

I have been mining for over 24 hours @ 97.3 Mhash/s. Shouldn't I have at least obtained .01 bitcoin by now? How do I verify the mining that I am doing is transferring into my Wallet?

Comment: Are you mining with a mining pool? I mined like 2 consecutive weeks with a MacBook Pro and had only 0.01 BTC by then. Mining with not-optimized hardware is really senseless.

Answer (score 2):

If you are solo mining against your own bitcoin server, then for each hash your miner tries it either solves the block (and earns 50BTC [plus transaction fees], provided it doesn't get orphaned), or doesn't (and earns nothing).

If you're mining with a pool, then payment depends on the pool's payment system. If for example it is PPLNS (Pay Per Last N Shares) with a value of 500,000 for N, then you don't get paid anything unless a block is solved within the 500,000 "shares" mined following each share that you submit. Let us know the pool you're using (or the payment mechanism), and we will be able to provide some more info.

With 97.3Mhash/s, I'd (roughly) estimate you'd earn around 0.04 to 0.05BTC per 24hrs with a difficulty of 2,100,000 (approx the current difficulty).