# Does my wallet need to be unlocked to mine?

Tags: wallet, miner-configuration

Currently I am mining at around 775Mh/s and have been for only 12 hours.  I want to make sure everything is setup properly.

I have encrypted my wallet and Bitcoin is reporting that the wallet is **encrypted** and **locked**.  Does the wallet need to be unlocked in order for the mining process to yield its results?

[This question was helpful.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/mining-and-bitcoin-wallet)

Comment: Note that 775Mh/s is absolutely nothing and I doubt you'll ever get any payout. You need something a 100x (probably 1000x) faster to expect anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be. Mining doesn't require private keys, only (part of) the public one. Having only the address of the destination is enough, so the wallet can be locked.